# Develop app only to be used for in app purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing a free app about marine life conservation.  I am working with a foundation to help them raise money.  I have an paid app in the iOS store now.  While i am certain of the answer, i would like to ask and hopefully be pleasantly surprised.
Is it possible to create an app that is only available via an in app purchase?  I would like of offer my app with the foundations' logos throughout the app, instead of my own, but i do not want this special app to be readily available on it's own.

Possible via any creative measures?

Comment: Could you develop it as a stand-alone application then issue someone with a promo code when they complete the in-app transaction. Then using that promo code they can gain access to your other app? Or assume the user has already downloaded the other application and deep-link into it using a unique code they get from the in-app transaction?

Comment: Hi Ollie, that would be fine.  Where would i store the "other app" so they can retrieve it with the special branding?  Can this be in the app store?

Comment: Yeah it will be, if someone random was to download it, it could just display a landing page and thats it. Then if someone with a deep link/promo code accesses it then they get to 'unlock' the app in a sense. Would that help?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thank you

Comment: Can you rewrite this as an answer and I will confirm it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting problem, a possible solution could be:

You will have your existing application with the in-app purchases that will give the user either a promo code or a deep link to your other application.

The other application will be essentially empty if someone random opens it, then will 'unlock' when a user has a code/link opens it.

If you did want to try the deep-linking, i've used Branch before that is quite easy to use. Link: https://branch.io